# NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSCFString unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, 32bit-64bit, jsonmodel

While using `JSONModel` to parse my models I found this Exception.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSCFString unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1782210c0
```

The problem got place inside `JSONModel.m` because it depends on `[NSObject setValue:forKey:]`.

I found a way to easily reproducing it.

```
@property NSUInteger uintegerProperty;
[...]
[self setValue:@"1" forKey:@"uintegerProperty"];
```

This works on 32 bits because `setValue` ends up calling `longLongVaue` defined in `NSString`, but in the case of 64 bits it's calling `unsignedLongLongValue` which is undefined in `NSString`.

In my particular case, the problem is this `enum` used in a model.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, kNotificationTypeEnum)
{
    kNotificationTypeResponse = 1,
    kNotificationTypeAlert = 2
};
```

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Stack trace

```
2014-12-31 17:48:43.789 mobile-iOS[17851:613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString unsignedLongLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f1feeb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b99495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001118f099e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c2a65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b8ad8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b8a938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010ff2449b _NSSetUnsignedLongLongValueForKeyWithMethod + 63
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010fed5530 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    7   mobile-iOS                          0x000000010ee1834c -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 140
    8   UIKit                               0x000000011051b3d9 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 264
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011051bbe1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1605
    10  UIKit                               0x000000011051fa0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110530d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000110531216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    13  mobile-iOS                          0x000000010eedf48b -[MMApplication sendEvent:] + 331
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000110521086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112df671a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112df61e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b1b679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b1b44e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b44903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b43d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  UIKit                               0x000000011051f2e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000110520e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    23  mobile-iOS                          0x000000010ee2af23 main + 243
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011230b5c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Signal: 6 (signal SIGABRT)
```

Comment: Can you pass the value as an `NSNumber` instead of an `NSString`?  I.e., `... setValue:@1 ...` instead?

Comment: Yes, that works but in my case I'm parsing the data directly from a web feed that is sent as NSString.

Comment: Exception stack trace?

Comment: I've added the stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just use a shorter integer type for the property, like uint32_t. The second easiest would be to add a category on NSString that provides the missing method.

Comment: I end up adding a category by simply implementing the message
`- (unsigned long long)unsignedLongLongValue
 {
  return self.longLongValue;
 }`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The finish solution to solve this problem:

```
@implementation NSString (UnsignedLongLongValue)

- (unsigned long long)unsignedLongLongValue {

    return self.longLongValue;
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar error with `iPhone 5` except that instead of `unsignedLongLongValue` we got `longValue` error. So we have used same category approach with following code:

```
@implementation NSString (LongValue)

- (long)longValue {
    return (long) self.longLongValue;
}

@end
```